# Inner renderings not displaying

Tags: sitecore

In a page, I have a rendering with a placeholder, Offcanvas.cshtml

```
<div data-ads-offcanvas-id="@Model.Id" class="ads-offcanvas @Html.GetCssStyles()">
@{
    <a data-ads-offcanvas-trigger-id="@Model.Id" class="ads-close-button" href="#0">X</a>
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder(LayoutHelper.GetPlaceholder(Placeholders.AccordionSection, Model.Id))
}
```

and inside that rendering, I plan to put another rendering with a placeholder named Modal.cshtml

```
<div data-ads-modal-container="@Model.Id" class="ads-modal-container">
<div class="ads-modal-dialog">
    <div class="ads-close-box">
        <a data-ads-modal-id="@Model.Id" href="#0">X</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ads-modal-content">
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder(LayoutHelper.GetPlaceholder(Placeholders.AccordionSection, Model.Id))
    </div>
</div>
```

So it looks like:

```
-Offcanvas
+-Modal
++-Text content
```

When I put text content inside the Modal rendering, the content is not rendered. I'm guessing that it only renders that first few renderings and fail to do so when the renderings became highly nested.

Is there a solution to render components to the very-most child?

Thanks guys!

EDIT:
Here's the code for GetPlaceholder:

```
public static string GetPlaceholder(string name, Guid id)
    {
        return $"{name}_{id}";
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for this LayoutHelper.GetPlaceholder so we can see what that is doing. It looks like both of the renderings shown here have the same placeholder name. Are you trying to do Dynamic Placeholders? There may be a better solution available.

Comment: @NathanHase I've made edits, so basically GetPlacehoder just names the placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic placeholders are a bit more complicated than generating a unique placeholder key. The generated key still needs to resolve back to a real placeholder that is defined in Sitecore.

Check out the [Integrated Dynamic Placeholder module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/I/Integrated_Dynamic_Placeholders.aspx).

This will provide an Html helper similar to your current implementation:

```
@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("[Placeholder Name]")
```